# Where does StringIO allocates memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, io, size

Probably silly question: Where does StringIO allocates memory?

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys


buff = StringIO()
buff.write('This goes into the buffer. Don"t know what to say more.')
print(buff.__sizeof__())
buff.write('This goes next. blablablabla!!1!!!!')
print(sys.getsizeof(buff))

>> 56
>> 56
```

I know about `.tell()` method. But I wonder about how object represents in memory.

Comment: I think the better question, is what does `__sizeof__` *actually* tell you?

Comment: Please try to clarify the question.  All Python objects need to allocate memory, and the Python internal API uses a memory allocator for this purpose.  StringIO() is no different from anything else.  Why are you interested in specifically that type of object?

Comment: BTW, `.tell()` doesn't need to _tell_ anything about real bytes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell (it's documented as an opaque handle to a stream position; guess what? it looks much like bytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see how it's working under the hood, you can read the source for `io.StringIO` in the CPython codebase: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_io/stringio.c

I found the answer to my question, which is "Does StringIO(initial_value) copy the underlying string to the buffer (if you only read it)", which is YES (look at `_io_StringIO___init___impl()`, from line 732 (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_io/stringio.c#L732), and then at `write_str()` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_io/stringio.c#L177)

Going back to your question, there is the C-struct `stringio`, which has the value `buf_size` -- this is the real number of allocated bytes in the StringIO, which may be greater than the number of bytes you've put in!

Actually, StringIO overallocates just in case, about 1.125 times, foreseeing future additions to the buffer, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_io/stringio.c#L99

Unfortunatelly, we don't have access to the `buf_size` struct member from Python. If you want to keep track of how much you've written, either sum the returns from `.write()`, believe what `.tell()` tells you, or get the string out and check it's length:

```
len(buff.getvalue())
```